# js, css, images are not loading in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter

I have a project in CodeIgnitor. I downloaded it from hosting server and try to run it on localhost. but strange, home page is not loading. I checked images, css and js were in there respective folders but I cannot access from localhost. as I copied and paste image url or js url in browser to run, it took me to google map url.

I'm not able to catch the problem, whether it is `.htaccess`  or some thing else is preventing me to load images on localhost.

Comment: what is the actual path of CSS and JS located ??

Comment: Make sure you set your base_url in config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';` and make sure you assets are out side of application folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be 1 of these 3 things:

1. Config
2. HTML markup
3. Directory permission

Answers:

1. (config/config.php) Set a valid value to $config['base_url'] key.
2. Try first use 'pure' HTML to load resources. If it loads, then you are using the path wrong - fix it dynamically later.
3. I dont know if you are using unix like system or windows. Anyway directory permission can cause this kind of problem sometimes. To fix is you need to apply a permission according to your system.

I hope it works. Please comment if you are sure that is not one of this 3 issues.

Comment: Nice!
If my advice above helped you, please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use base_url in image/file path for EX::

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/pages/img/logo.png">

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/pages/js/example.js"> </script>
```

You nedd to load URL helper in config file to use base_url

Comment: I m already using this as showing dynamically.
but they are successfully loading online then y not on localhost

Comment: check your base url in config file or open console in your browser and identify error

Comment: base_url is empty and in browser showing error that 404 image not found.

error:
GET http://localhost/nowdial/static/upload/8432994department-store-1778719_960_720.jpg 404 (Not Found);

this path is correct and image is present there but not showing

Comment: when clicking on above link on localhost, following message is showing

404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: you  load URL helper in config file??